# Flex: get visible size of component (Flex 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have DataGrid with horizontal scrollbar. How can I get its visible width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myDG.width`? Or I misunderstood your question?